# hashCode() value changes between executions

Tags: java, serialization, hashcode

**hashCode** of an object has to be consistent for that object throughout one execution of the application-- 
for any object **o, o.hashCode()** should return the same **int** value.

However, this doesn't have to be from one run-time to another: **o.hashCode()** 
can return some other value and this is perfectly alright by the [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

**HashMap** calculates the right bucked based on the **hashCode** value.

My Q is: how is this value change between one session to another handled?
Does serialization have features to handle this?

So, suppose I built a hash and stored it on the disk. 2 weeks after, I invoked the application and am 
running it. I'm looking up an object in the hash. By these, the **hashCode** of 
this object is/can be now different than before 
and I wont be able to find it although it is there in the hash.

Answer (score 7):

This works because hashtables are not serialized as hashtables. They are serialized in a custom way. So when deserialized, the hashtable will be rebuilt using the new hashcodes.

Comment: is/n't there a way to store the HashMap as is-- with its entire structure?

Comment: @Roam Why would you want to? You are already aware of one reason not to do it - the changeability of hash codes between runs. Also, a hash table is organized for rapid search, not space efficiency.

Comment: @Roam: You don't need to ask that question. From your perspective, you only care that the `HashMap` is restored. Note that if all elements in the serialized `HashMap` use the base `Object.hashCode()` implementation (which generally returns the memory address of the object instance), you'd still have to get the list of objects in the hash map in other ways (`values()`) before finding those objects in the hash map, as newly instantiated objects could never have the same hash code as an object in the map. This is why you should generally implement your own `hashCode()` based on business values.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan to figure what i can/not do with it. but i guess there isn't & meaningless to keep it on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

The general contract of `Object.hashCode()` does, as you say, specify that the hash code can change between runs.

However, if you require a hash code that does *not* change between runs, it is simply up to you to override `hashCode()` with your own implementation that guarantees that.

Your application requirements impose additional rules, but these do not break the general `Object.hashCode()` contract. Therefore, you can safely implement your own `hashCode()`  that meets your requirements here without risk of breaking anything else.  Note that `hashCode()` does not *require* hash codes to differ between runs, it merely allows it.

The reason, by the way, that the spec allows this is because the base implementation just returns the memory address of the object, which can differ between runs. This is sometimes appropriate for quick, one-off uses but generally isn't. You usually want to implement a `hashCode()` that computes a hash code based on business values, that is consistent between runs and that is the same for objects that are equal at the business level (i.e. two `Integer` instances that have the same value).

As Robin Green pointed out, Java's `HashMap` implements custom serialization that is independent of the hash value of the object at the time of storage. *However*, if you were to implement your own hash table, and simply stored hash values of objects, you would *not* be guaranteed that you could find the object after deserializing your hash table (unless of course you only stored objects in it with a consistent `hashCode()`).

Answer (score 1):

When you serialize the hashtable, you serialize values, not hash codes. Serializing hash code is a bad idea.

Comment: Hash codes are used to determine the hash bucket; they are computed, and do not need to be stored. Indeed, they cannot be cached by the hashtable, because that would cause a problem of infinite regress - the hashtable would need another hashtable to look up the hashcodes in.