# Print object without memory id in crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

If I print an object with puts , the memory id will be printed.
Is there a way to print the object (with all the elements inside) without memory id ?

The same problem appears when I want to hash an object (with `OpenSSL::Digest.new("SHA256")` ), 
The memory id of the object will be included into the hash, 
so if I hash 2 object with the same components , they will have different hash. How I can prevent this ?

Comment: Example please?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the string representation of the object to hash something

Comment: Instead of asking help building a solution, you should first explain your problem. Maybe we can help you with a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own #to_s(IO) method on the object. https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/Object.html#to_s-instance-method
or a whole new method "give me something hashable" or even define the [hash](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/Object.html#hash-instance-method) method...just be careful because #hash may not be [stable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339032/32453) between invocations...