Why does calling hashcode() change the hashcode value of my variable?
Could someone explain the following behavior for .hashcode().
When working with the two classes below I get different values for .hashcode() calls. Now I am just trying to understand the reason behind this behavior. I'm working with the default implementation of .hashcode(). I am not overriding it nor do I want to use it for hashtables or hashmaps. ( I understand this is the one of the main reasons for hashcodes)
If I execute Main 10 times I would get the same value for contact3 hashcode. hashcode = 1555009629 in this case.
Now...
If I execute the same Main 10 other times but comment out the call to hashcode in mergeContactData then the hashcode value in Main for contact3 would change to 41359092.
The two following questions talk about overriding hashcode() and explanations using maps and tables which is not the intended use for this question. This question simply about behavior of default implementation.
Reason behind JVM's default Object.HashCode() implementation
Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Contact contact = new Contact("Gustavo", "xxx", 5555555555L);
      Contact contact2 = new Contact("Gustavo", "xxx", 5555555555L);
      Contact contact3 = contact.mergeContactData(contact2);
      System.out.println("Hashcode for contact3: " + contact3.hashCode());

   }
}

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Contact {

   private String name;
   private Set<String> emails = new HashSet<String>();
   private Set<String> phones = new HashSet<>();

   public Contact(String name) {
      this(name, null, 0);
   }

   public Contact(String name, String email) {
      this(name, email, 0);
   }

   public Contact(String name, long phone) {
      this(name, null, phone);
   }

   public Contact(String name, String email, long phone) {
      this.name = name;
      if (email != null) {
         this.emails.add((email));
      }

      if (phone < 1000000000) {
         System.out.println("Invalid Phone Number");
         return;
      }
      String phoneNumber = "";
      phoneNumber += "(" +
              String.valueOf(phone / 10000000);
      phone = phone % 10000000;
      phoneNumber += ")" + String.valueOf(phone / 10000);
      phone = phone % 10000;
      phoneNumber += "-" + String.valueOf(phone);

      this.phones.add(phoneNumber);
   }

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public Contact mergeContactData(Contact contact) {

      if (this.name.equals(contact.name)) {
         Contact newContact = new Contact(this.name);
         newContact.emails.addAll(this.emails);
         newContact.phones.addAll(this.phones);
         newContact.emails.addAll(contact.emails);

         System.out.println(newContact.hashCode());

         contact.phones.forEach(s -> newContact.phones.add(s));
         return newContact;
      } else {
         System.out.println("Not the same contact name");
         return this;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return this.name + " -> emails: " + this.emails + " Phone: " + this.phones;
   }


}


The answer to this may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339002/hashcode-value-changes-between-executions

You are not overriding hashCode(), so it is using the implementation from Object, which is returning a fixed value per instance. The hashcode is different every time you run your program. Printing the hash code does not matter, the value is different simply because you are executing the program multiple times.

If the hash code really is dependent on another call, you have to provide a [mre] and clearly show and explain that this call is responsible for changing the code (hint: it's not).

@knittl That is what I had understood, that every time I run this I should get different results but I dont'. I'm not know sure how else to give an example other that if you could please copy these two classes and try yourself running them several times with and without commenting out the call to hashcode in mergeContactData.

Additional classes loaded or more objects instantiated means the "memory addresses" (simplified) can be different for your object. Or the garbage collector has to run earlier/later, meaning a different hash code is calculated. Note that printing isn't the problem, a standalone call to newContact.hashCode() will trigger the same behavior. Also note that moving the call to after your .forEach-lambda invocation does not affect the result. Commenting that lambda line does.

@knittl I understand that I'm not overriding hashcode(). What I am trying to understand is why the hashcode value of contact3 in Main is different simply because of the call in mergeContactData.
If I execute Main 10 times with the hashcode call commented out the result is: 41359092
If I execute Main 10 times with the hashcode call NOT commented out the result is: 1555009629
Is there something to explain this behavior?

@GustavoPalomino The implementation of Object.hashCode() depends on the actual JVM you are using. I can confirm what you see with OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17.0.13_p11 (build 17.0.13+11) on a linux machine, but that doesn't mean that the hashCode() has to work that way everywhere, only what is defined on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--.

But what are you trying to accomplish? The result of hashCode() is not defined to be a certain value. The only guarantee is that it will be the same integer value if you have equal instances (and without equals/hashCode overridden, that means you have only a single instance with the given identity)

@knittl I wasn't trying to accomplish anything but rather understand the odd behavior. Creating new variables (even a new arrayList with 50000 capacity) before creating newContact didn't change the hashcode value of contact3( which really is newContact). As you pointed out before the placement of the hashcode() call changes the value. I guess I wanted someone to explain to me why this behavior was happening and I guess the only explanation is the JVM implementation and not the actual classes implementation?... FYI Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)

@knittl I also noticed that switching contact.phones.forEach(s -> newContact.phones.add(s)); for newContact.phones.addAll(contact.phones); will yield that same result for contact3 hashcode regardless where the hashcode call for newContact  is placed.I really just wanted to understand the behavior.

@GustavoPalomino Again, it's implementation detail of the actual JVM you are using. You have to check the source code of the JVM how the hashcode for java.lang.Object is calculated.

It's quite possible that if a different number of objects are allocated first, objects will get different hash codes than they would otherwise.  There are lots of places where objects could be allocated.

@LouisWasserman while this might explain this behavior for other cases, in this case the only difference is a call to hashcode()

You can even change the default hashcode generation with a commandline option, and even set it so all objects have the same default hashcode (!).

@GustavoPalomino: You're printing the hash code, which requires creating a String to hold its representation, which has an underlying char[] object that gets allocated too.  Even how long the printed string is might matter.

@LouisWasserman This might actually be the closest to an actual reason to the behavior. If I remember correctly moving the hashcode() call to after the forEach would not change the hash value. Which would make sense in the terms of memory being allocated. I also noticed before that even the standalone call to hashcode() would trigger the same behavior but that would also make sense because hashcode() still allocation memory in the return type.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049632/112968: "As to HotSpot JVM, it uses random number generator for initial calculation of identity hashCode. After the hashCode is calculated for the first time, it is saved in the object header so that subsequent calls to identityHashCode will return the same value.". So it uses a random number generator and the first time it is called, the value is stored. So it depends on when you first call hashCode (and how many other random values were generated before calling the method)

hashCode isn't magic, it's just a method, but one that is defined in java.lang.Object itself. If you don't override it, that's the one you get.
And that one returns, and I'm vastly oversimplifying here, 'the memory address' of the object. In other words, that default hashCode impl is different every time you start a JVM. It has nothing to do with whether or not you remark anything out. The merge method returns a new contact (why? Because it runs new Contact and returns what that produced), and all objects have a 'random' hashCode that is different every time you start the JVM. Just make a simple contact and print the hashCode of that, then rerun that code a few times. Different hashCode every time (or not - a JVM does not have to return a different value. What it returns is unspecified, and doesn't need to be).
A class gets to decide which things are and are not equal; the fact that 2 contact objects have the exact same field values does not imply they are equal; that is up to you (the author of Contact) to decide. Some concepts aren't equal even if they have the same data. For example, 2 file handles to the same file aren't the same handle. By default, no object is equal to anything other than itself, not even to other instances of the same type with the same contents.
And hashCode is simple: The rule is - if 2 objects are equal (as per .equals, then they must have the same hashCode() value. That's the only rule (and it does not work in reverse; 2 objects with the same hashcode do not necessarily have to be equal).
If your intent is for 2 instances of Contact to count as being 'equal', then you have to write an equals and hashCode method. Or have your IDE generate it, or use lombok to generate them, or use record.

I agree with everything you have said. However, I'm not questioning equality of 2 objects.
The hashcode value for contact3 in Main is the same every time I execute Main when the hash call in mergeData is commented out.
If it is NOT commented out the hashcode value for contact3 is different than when it is commented out but still the same everytime I execute it while still not commented out.

The JVM makes no guarantee about how it computes the hashcode in the default Object implementation. That's the short answer.  I am going to guess on a longer answer based on what @rzwitserloot says that it could be a memory location. Let's say the class/data uses 100 bytes of memory and you create 3 copies and they get allocated the next free memory, their addresses are 0, 100, 200.  Now alter the code (by un/commenting that method) and your code is longer/shorter... meaning the memory addresses are different... QED.

It doesn't return the memory address. Oversimplifying is OK, but you're oversimplifying to the point that you perpetuate a severe misunderstanding of what the default hashcode is. See also What's the default hash value of an object on 64 bit JVM
